# Twitter Bootstrap Align Center.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to put the entire thing in center. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.

Here is my code and I made sure that I have the .container in the right place. But still, they are not aligning.

Help guys?!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Home- Argyle's Automobile</title>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container banner-header">
    <h1><a href="#">Argyle's Automobile</a></h1>
 </div>

 <!--Navbar-->
 <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container"> <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            </ul></div>
</div>

<!--Marketing Area-->
<div class="container"><div class="hero-unit">

    <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>
    <br />
    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. <br />Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris<br /> condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    <br />
    <br />

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Get Started</a>
</div></div>
</div>

<!--Content-->
<div id='content' class='container row-fluid'>
    <div class="span4">
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: good formatting practice - always use double quotes in HTML for attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole !# in a `div.container` and then remove the extra closing `</div>` in your hero unit. You don't need to keep using `.container` on the inner HTML but it's fine to do so.

Here's a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kgfOjyOla6gAEPumLXd2?p=preview

Here are the related BootStrap 2 docs:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 1):

Your markup using Bootstrap is incorrect. See the Twitter Bootstrap website for tutorials on how to structure the markup.

```
<div class="row-fluid"></div>
```

Should always sit inside `<div class="container"></div>`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid